# NullReferenceException after calling ShowDialog() in System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, exception

I have a WPF application and sometimes app crashes just after I call ShowDialog() on Window (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When application starts I open a main dialog (it's always opened) then I want to open a new child dialog (see below ShowModal method), and usually everything works fine but sometimes after calling ShowDialog() (see below code snippet) it throws System.NullReferenceException in PresentationFramework.dll in method System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param).

After calling ShowDialog() the window is shown in App, then when I click anywhere on it (for example a textbox), it throws NullReferenceException .

I'm unable to reproduce crashing pattern it behaves completely randomized. And I'm starting to go crazy because I don't have any clue how to trace where is the problem.

This is the snippet from my code:

```
private Window Wnd { get; set; }
public bool ShowModal(ViewModel vm)
{
    if( Wnd == null )
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "Window was already closed" );
    }

    Wnd.DataContext = vm;
    Result = Wnd.ShowDialog().Equals(true);

    return Result;
 }
```

**Wnd is not null** it contains instance of window I want to show. Exception is thrown in this line

```
Result = Wnd.ShowDialog().Equals(true);
```

actually after Wnd.ShowDialog()

Thrown exception snapshot:

```
System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
HResult = -2147467261
Message = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Data = {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
InnerExcpetion = null
Source = PresentationCore
StackTrace       
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ThreadMessageEventHandler.Invoke(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at Intes.Utility.VisualizerService.UiWindow.ShowModal(ViewModel vm) in d:\Coder\Branch-AT\Source\Utilities\VisualizerService\Window abstraction\Implementation\UiWindow.cs:line 109


   // this part of call stack is not important, but I will leave it
   at A13.ViewModels.CalGroupExplorer.CalGroupExplorerPanelViewModel.NewMessage(IEnumerable`1 referenceIDs) in d:\Coder\Branch-AT\Source\A13\A13\ViewModels\CalGroupExplorer\CalGroupExplorerPanelViewModel.cs:line 159
   at A13.ViewModels.EntryViewModel.AddReferencedMessage() in d:\Coder\Branch-AT\Source\A13\A13\ViewModels\CalGroupExplorer\EntryViewModel.cs:line 147
   at A13.ViewModels.EntryViewModel.<get_AddReferencedMessageCommand>b__4(Object param) in d:\Coder\Branch-AT\Source\A13\A13\ViewModels\CalGroupExplorer\EntryViewModel.cs:line 136
   at Intes.Utility.Wpf.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in d:\Coder\Branch-AT\Source\Utilities\Wpf\RelayCommand.cs:line 70
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
```

It seems like bug in .NET Framework, I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 for both projects A13 and Intes. A13 is main project , while Intes is referenced (method ShowModal is in class that is in project Intes). A13 is compiled as platform target: x86, while Intes as platform target: AnyCPU.

I'm running application in DEBUG mode on Windows 8.1 on x64 processor (Application has to be a x86).

Does anybody have any idea where could be the problem or any help how to trace the problem?

Comment: OnPreprocessMessage() only does something non-trivial for keystrokes.  If your program bombs like this on a mouse click then you have a very serious corruption problem.  The "must be x86" requirement does hint that native code being capable of screwing things up badly.  You can't get help with that here, you need to record a minidump and call Microsoft Support for assistance.

Comment: Oh wait, I wasn't so accurate. Now when I think, it crashes after I click on textbox and press a key. But as I said usually it works, sometimes it crashes. Also I didn't notice such behavior on Windows 7 x64, but I can not be a 100% sure, now I'm trying to reproduce it on Win 7 and everything works for now.

Comment: I've managed to compile projects as x64, but the problem still occurs ...

Comment: ... in Win7 x64 my app also crashes with the same issue

Comment: I got a report from a user about this behavior: click in a textbox and BOOM, nullreferencexception with that stack trace... and it doesn't always happen... it's totally random